# wkhtmltopdf not adding footer and header on pages

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using Laravel 10 with wkhtmltopdf barryvdh/laravel-snappy library to generate pdfs
When I try to generate pdf the header is applied only on top of first page and footer is applied only on bottom of last page.

Header and footer should be applied on every page.

I instead of adding footer and header in main html file I tried other way using

```
$pdf->setOption('footer-html, $pathToFooterHtmlFile);
```

But in this way footer didn't appear at all.

Where is a problem? is it something not configured in system or incorrect html/php code?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1.10-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        wkhtmltopdf \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        nano \
        libxslt1.1 \
        libxslt1-dev \
        unzip \
        git \
        gnupg \
        libzip-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libwebp-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql --with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd xsl pdo pdo_pgsql pdo_mysql opcache zip

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf;
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf;

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-install exif \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.log='/tmp/xdebug.log'" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "memory_limit='256M'" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-extra.ini \
    && echo "upload_max_filesize='10M'" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-extra.ini

COPY ./opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opc

RUN apt-get update  \
    && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg \
    && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings \
    && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x nodistro main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list \
    && apt-get update  \
    && apt-get install nodejs -y

RUN set -xe; \
    curl -fsSL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -; \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list; \
    apt-get update >/dev/null; \
    apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install >/dev/null \
        nodejs \
        yarn \
    ;\
    apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*;

ENV PHP_IDE_CONFIG "serverName=blog_app"

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer --version=2.3.8 && chmod +x /usr/bin/composer

# Set timezone
RUN rm /etc/localtime \
    && ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Warsaw /etc/localtime \
    && "date" \
    && printf '[PHP]\ndate.timezone = "Europe/Warsaw"\n' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/tzone.ini

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>aAAAA</title>
    <style>
        body { font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif; }
        #footer {
            position: fixed;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        #header {
            position: fixed;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: green;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<footer id="footer">
    <p>asdasdasd</p>
</footer>
<header id="header">
    <p>tttt</p>
</header>

<div style="width: 100%;">
    {{$text}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
$fileName = storage_path('tmp-pdfs/' . 'new_pdf.pdf');
        $faker = Faker::create('en_EN');
        $text = $faker->realText(50000, 5);

        $pdf = App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');

        $pdf = $pdf->loadView('pdf.pdf', ['text' => $text]);
        $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
        $pdf->save($fileName);

        return $pdf->download($fileName);
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: @BadPiggie Sorry, I edited question. Footer and Header should be applied on every page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add header and footer on every page with wkhtmltopdf unpatched qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832795/how-to-add-header-and-footer-on-every-page-with-wkhtmltopdf-unpatched-qt)